# How to fix unmatched number of blocks in 2 columns

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file in which the last 2 columns ARE NOT MATCHED in number of blocks (`$3` has 3 blocks but `$4` has 2) in some rows. How can I fix it throughout file. Thank you

what I have:

```
162   167   4,92,4    2,19
143   164   2,4       54,32
532   843   6,4,5     43,23,53
```

what I want:

```
143   164   2,4       54,32
532   843   6,4,5     43,23,53
```

Comment: One can't fix it if one doesn't know what it's supposed to look like.

Comment: and how should look the "fixed version"?

Comment: please fix the "what I have / what I want" part, as right now I can't see what you really want to do ? (get rid of the 1st line only ? why?) (or do you mean to "only keep lines which have exactly as many comma_separated_values in their 3rd column and their 4th columns" ? ie, only those 2 columns are to be compared and you print lines which have as many commas (or fields) in them?)

Answer (score 4):

try

```
awk 'split($3,A,",") == split($4,B,",")'
```

as per man awk

> split(s, a [, r [, seps] ])
>                                  Split  the string s into the array a and the separators array seps on the regular expression r, and return
>                                  the number of fields.

- default awk action is implicit print

Comment: @BehrouzMahmoudi If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).  If you're happy with the answer, accepting it and maybe even upvoting it is the best way to say "Thank You!" :-)

Answer (score 1):

To filter out the lines that has different number of comma-delimited values in the 3rd and 4th fields:

```
awk '{ nc3=split($3,a,","); nc4=split($4,a,",") } nc3 == nc4' data.in
```

The `awk` function `split` will split the given field on the regular expression in its third argument (a comma in this case) and store the generated fields in the array in its second argument (`a` here).  We don't use the resulting array, but instead use the foct that `split` also returns the number of generated array entries.

If these numbers (`nc3` and `nc4`) are identical, the line will be printed.

Answer (score 1):

Simple ***awk*** approach:

```
awk -F"[[:space:]]+|," '!(NF%2){ print }' file
```

The output:

```
143   164   2,4       54,32
532   843   6,4,5     43,23,53
```

---

- `!(NF%2)` - considering only lines which have even number of items (treating whitespace(s) and `,` as field separators)